# Java configuring in properties file

Tags: java

I want to configure a property in my properties file. But that will not be a static value. For example,

`var=abc some_unknown_string_here def`

I will set the value for the unknown string within the java program. Is it possible to have a configuration like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a hack you can do like this:

In properties file:

```
var = abc%_%xyz
```

In java file

```
//--- code to load property file
String propVar = properties.getProperty("var");
String myVar = propVar.replace("%_%","the_string_want_to_set_here");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store format string as a property, e.g.:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("foo", "hi, %s");

String s = properties.getProperty("foo");
System.out.println(String.format(s, "bar"));
```